# Unusually large number of httpd processes and high CPU load on MongoDB replica set members

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, httpd, mongodb, cpu-usage

I am investigating a strange behavior on 3 CentOS machines serving as a MongoDB replica set, whereas one of them is also hosting a PHP web app utilizing the MongoDB replica set. The basic setup is as follows:

- **Node 1**: CentOS 5.8, MongoDB 2.6.10 (acting as PRIMARY), Apache 2.2.23 (running a PHP web app with MongoDB driver 1.6.10)
- **Node 2**: CentOS 5.11, MongoDB 2.6.10 (acting as SECONDARY), Apache 2.2.23 (running nothing than an empty index.html, called up by Nagios every few minutes)
- **Node 3**: CentOS 5.11, MongoDB 2.6.10 (acting as SECONDARY), Apache 2.2.23 (running nothing than an empty index.html, called up by Nagios every few minutes)

Now, all of them are experiencing a nearly constant 100% CPU load. The load is caused by a large number of httpd processes being launched. Even on nodes 2 and 3, which have almost no HTTP traffic. The CPU usage of the mongod process is vanishingly small on each machine.

This is what the `top` output on node 2 looks like:

[image]

The output looks very similar on nodes 1 and 3.
This is what the httpd access log on node 2 looks like:

[image]

Having a large number of httpd processes but a very small amount of actual HTTP requests seems strange to me.
When I check `netstat -p` on node 2 I see something like this:

[image]

The open mongod sockets should be the replication workers or replica set heartbeats, but what is really striking in the `netstat -p` output: The additional number of open httpd (?!) sockets coming from MongoDB port 27017 on their counterpart (node 3).

As a result of this, logging on to the machines (e. g. via SSH) becomes tremendously slow after a while. Restarting httpd works in the short term, the number of httpd processes and CPU load instantly drops to a normal level. But after a few hours, the httpd processes/sockets fill up again and the machine is back on 100% CPU load. Restarting httpd does not have any impact on the replica set's operation.

I am not sure but I guess the prefork/worker configuration of Apache is nothing special:

```
<IfModule prefork.c>
    StartServers       8
    MinSpareServers    5
    MaxSpareServers   20
    ServerLimit      256
    MaxClients       256
    MaxRequestsPerChild  4000
</IfModule>

<IfModule worker.c>
    StartServers         2
    MaxClients         150
    MinSpareThreads     25
    MaxSpareThreads     75 
    ThreadsPerChild     25
    MaxRequestsPerChild  0
</IfModule>
```

To cut a long story short...

- Is it really the MongoDB replica set, which is somehow affecting the web server and why?
- Why does Apache (httpd) even care about the sockets buzzing on these random 37000 ~ 60999 ports? (Shouldn't it just handle ports 80/443?)
- What can I do to solve or at least to isolate the problem?

Comment: By all means, I feel the index page on the secondary nodes are being accessed by a lot of users.

Comment: No, there is not a single user except Nagios (see fig. of Apache's access log). Futhermore, this would not explain the huge number of internal connections being kept open, which can be seen in `netstat -p`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out the huge number of httpd processes, open connections and the consequential high CPU load somehow resulted from an old and broken SSL configuration (duplicate `VirtualHost` with different expired certificates) in Apache's `conf.d` folder.

Since there were no error messages at all I triple-checked the configurations and made some trial-and-error attempts. Removing the SSL configuration led to a significant decline of launched httpd processes as well as connections being left open. The CPU load dropped to a regular level.

The problem is solved, wherever this strange phenomenon came from and what the broken SSL configuration had to do with it. Nonetheless I am still wondering about the weird relation of the MongoDB replica set members and httpd sockets still appearing in `netstat -p`.